# Sample Application "Articles" does not start on Oracle WebCenter Sites Jump Start Kit with Tomcat

Tags: java, oracle, tomcat, webcenter-sites

I'm new on the Oracle WebCenter Sites platform and I'm Following step-by-step the documentation at this link: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E29542_01/doc.1111/e29634/wemlaunchingsampleapp.htm

I'm trying to install the sample application named "Articles" as shown in the link. After that I have compiled the application I move the .war file at the following path: "C:\Oracle\App_Server\apache-tomcat-7.0.42\Sites\webapps".

Then I Stop the Application Server and start it again. It creates the new folder in webapps folder "Articles-1.0" but when I try to go at the link localhost:9180/Articles-1.0/install.app as written in the documentation it gives me back "HTTP Status 404".

If I go on Tomcat Web Application Manager it told me that Articles-1.0 is not started and if I try to start it again it told me: "FAIL - Application at context path /articles-1.0 could not be started".

```
This is what there is written in catalina log file for the application:
mar 11, 2014 11:46:50 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deploying web application archive C:\Oracle\App_Server\apache-tomcat-7.0.42\Sites\webapps\articles-1.0.war
mar 11, 2014 11:46:52 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
mar 11, 2014 11:46:52 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/articles-1.0] startup failed due to previous errors
mar 11, 2014 11:46:52 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\Oracle\App_Server\apache-tomcat-7.0.42\Sites\webapps\cas
```

And this is what is written in localhost log file:

```
mar 11, 2014 11:46:39 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Set web app root system property: 'webapp.root' = [C:\Oracle\App_Server\apache-tomcat-7.0.42\Sites\webapps\cs\]
mar 11, 2014 11:46:39 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing log4j from [classpath:log4j.properties]
mar 11, 2014 11:46:39 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
mar 11, 2014 11:46:51 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
mar 11, 2014 11:46:52 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'ssolistener' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:883)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:839)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:440)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:380)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:264)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:261)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:164)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:429)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:728)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:380)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:255)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:199)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:45)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4939)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5434)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:976)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1653)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:100)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:61)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:877)
    ... 30 more
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "@casCacheMultiCastGroupPort@"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:492)
    at java.lang.Integer.<init>(Integer.java:677)
    at net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMICacheManagerPeerProviderFactory.createAutomaticallyConfiguredCachePeerProvider(RMICacheManagerPeerProviderFactory.java:115)
    at net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMICacheManagerPeerProviderFactory.createCachePeerProvider(RMICacheManagerPeerProviderFactory.java:61)
    at net.sf.ehcache.config.ConfigurationHelper.createCachePeerProviders(ConfigurationHelper.java:283)
    at net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.configure(CacheManager.java:443)
    at net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.init(CacheManager.java:302)
    at net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.<init>(CacheManager.java:234)
    at com.fatwire.cache.ehcache.EhCacheObjectCache._initCache(EhCacheObjectCache.java:730)
    at com.fatwire.cache.ehcache.EhCacheObjectCache.start(EhCacheObjectCache.java:564)
    at com.fatwire.wem.sso.cas.cache.SessionMappingStorage.<init>(SessionMappingStorage.java:48)
    at com.fatwire.wem.sso.cas.listener.CASListener.<clinit>(CASListener.java:15)
    ... 37 more

mar 11, 2014 11:46:52 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
mar 11, 2014 11:46:56 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing log4j from [classpath:log4j.properties]
mar 11, 2014 11:46:56 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
mar 11, 2014 11:47:02 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'cas'
mar 11, 2014 11:50:06 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
mar 11, 2014 11:50:07 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'ssolistener' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:883)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:839)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:440)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:380)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:264)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:261)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:164)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:429)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:728)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:380)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:255)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:199)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:45)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4939)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5434)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.start(ManagerServlet.java:1256)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.start(HTMLManagerServlet.java:714)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.doPost(HTMLManagerServlet.java:219)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.CsrfPreventionFilter.doFilter(CsrfPreventionFilter.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:611)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:100)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:61)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:877)
    ... 46 more
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "@casCacheMultiCastGroupPort@"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:492)
    at java.lang.Integer.<init>(Integer.java:677)
    at net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMICacheManagerPeerProviderFactory.createAutomaticallyConfiguredCachePeerProvider(RMICacheManagerPeerProviderFactory.java:115)
    at net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMICacheManagerPeerProviderFactory.createCachePeerProvider(RMICacheManagerPeerProviderFactory.java:61)
    at net.sf.ehcache.config.ConfigurationHelper.createCachePeerProviders(ConfigurationHelper.java:283)
    at net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.configure(CacheManager.java:443)
    at net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.init(CacheManager.java:302)
    at net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.<init>(CacheManager.java:234)
    at com.fatwire.cache.ehcache.EhCacheObjectCache._initCache(EhCacheObjectCache.java:730)
    at com.fatwire.cache.ehcache.EhCacheObjectCache.start(EhCacheObjectCache.java:564)
    at com.fatwire.wem.sso.cas.cache.SessionMappingStorage.<init>(SessionMappingStorage.java:48)
    at com.fatwire.wem.sso.cas.listener.CASListener.<clinit>(CASListener.java:15)
    ... 53 more

mar 11, 2014 11:50:07 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
mar 11, 2014 12:08:21 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
mar 11, 2014 12:08:21 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'ssolistener' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:883)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:839)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:440)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:380)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:264)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:261)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:164)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:429)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:728)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:380)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:255)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:199)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:45)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4939)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5434)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.start(ManagerServlet.java:1256)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.start(HTMLManagerServlet.java:714)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.doPost(HTMLManagerServlet.java:219)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.CsrfPreventionFilter.doFilter(CsrfPreventionFilter.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:611)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:100)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:61)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:877)
    ... 46 more
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "@casCacheMultiCastGroupPort@"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:492)
    at java.lang.Integer.<init>(Integer.java:677)
    at net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMICacheManagerPeerProviderFactory.createAutomaticallyConfiguredCachePeerProvider(RMICacheManagerPeerProviderFactory.java:115)
    at net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMICacheManagerPeerProviderFactory.createCachePeerProvider(RMICacheManagerPeerProviderFactory.java:61)
    at net.sf.ehcache.config.ConfigurationHelper.createCachePeerProviders(ConfigurationHelper.java:283)
    at net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.configure(CacheManager.java:443)
    at net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.init(CacheManager.java:302)
    at net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.<init>(CacheManager.java:234)
    at com.fatwire.cache.ehcache.EhCacheObjectCache._initCache(EhCacheObjectCache.java:730)
    at com.fatwire.cache.ehcache.EhCacheObjectCache.start(EhCacheObjectCache.java:564)
    at com.fatwire.wem.sso.cas.cache.SessionMappingStorage.<init>(SessionMappingStorage.java:48)
    at com.fatwire.wem.sso.cas.listener.CASListener.<clinit>(CASListener.java:15)
    ... 53 more

mar 11, 2014 12:08:21 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by modify

articles\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\classes\cas-cache.xml

file in this part:

```
        class="net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMICacheManagerPeerProviderFactory"

        properties="peerDiscovery=automatic, multicastGroupAddress=230.0.0.0,

                            multicastGroupPort=@casCacheMultiCastGroupPort@, timeToLive=0" />
```

change attribute multicastGroupPort=@casCacheMultiCastGroupPort@

with your JumpStart Kit port(my port was 9180)

multicastGroupPort=9180